# How to automatically create a terms based on each post of a post type

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy, terms, automation

I am working on a music site which has custom post types- `artists`, and `releases`. I have about 3,000 `artists`, and about 19,000 `releases` in my database. I'd like to create a new taxonomy term for each of these post types.

I have created a taxonomy called `artists`. I'd like to have each post of `post_type -> 'artist'` become a term in the taxonomy, automatically.

I'd then like to do the same with `releases`.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for editing these Tom.

Comment: Any ideas? Thanks y'all!